# from: can't read /var/mail/classes

Tags: python, class, terminal

I am trying to write a python program, and trying to learn classes. My program is as follows:

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, name, account_number, initial_amount, transactions):
        self.name = name
        self.no = account_number
        self.balance = initial_amount
        self.transactions = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        self.transactions += 1

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        self.transactions += 1

    def dump(self):
        s = '$s, %s, balance: %s, number of transactions: %s' %\
             (self.name, self.no, self.balance, self.transactions) 
        print s
```

In terminal, when i am in the folder the python program is located, I try to write from classes import Account to test my program, but the error code I get is: from: can't read /var/mail/classes. What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should not run python from the python program folder. Instead, you should launch python from the same directory where your code is located.

The `from classes import Account` will first look for a file named classes.py in your working folder. Then it will look through the other python paths.

Comment: That's not the problem here, though.